# Error On Create Project Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, zip, android-vectordrawable

I have Error on create Project in Android Studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library'.
>   Could not expand ZIP 'D:\program\android_sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\animated-vector-drawable\23.2.0\animated-vector-drawable-23.2.0.aar'.

[image]
How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: did you updated your buildToolsVersion to "23.2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ,

1. Check whether you have write access on both the android sdk and
   Android Studio directories.
2. if you are on Windows OS, also try to run Android Studio as
   Administrator by right clicking on the Studio's icon.

Answer (score 0):

run Android Studio as Administrator  and check if your project setting is properly set ~~this error occurred for me, it was because i directed to wrong  sdk folder